# Invoking Multiple Classes - Perl

Tags: perl

Hi I'm working on an extension system for a project of mine, what I'm trying to do is to load multiple packages so I could make use of them. I have a hash of packages with their keys, I want to use these keys as reference to access multiple methods. I could use Moose or Moo to extend these packages but I want to try something new.

Here's the code:

```
my %classes = (
    eng => 'EnglishClass',
    esp => 'SpanishClass',
    fre => 'FrenchClass',
    hin => 'HindiClass'
);
while ( my ( $classType, $className ) = each(%classes) ) {
    $self->{$classType} = $className->new();
}
```

It seems to be loading but when I try to access methods, the wrong package gets called even though I use the right key for reference.

Comment: The bug is elsewhere. Perhaps these objects mistakenly store some or all of their state in variables that are shared between objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works for me. Can you show how you are accessing the objects?

Here's my quick take on it;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my %classes = (
    eng => 'ENG',
    esp => 'ESP'
);

my $self = {};
while ( my ( $classType, $className ) = each(%classes) ) {
    $self->{$classType} = $className->new();
}

$self->{'eng'}->hello();

package ENG;
sub new { return bless {}, shift; }
sub hello { say 'Hello from ENG'; }

package ESP;
sub new { return bless {}, shift; }
sub hello { say 'Hello from ESP'; }

1;
```

Comment: This is how I access methods `$self->{eng}->hello();`

Comment: There may be something in your code that your not showing, as far as I can see the system should work with all the information so far provided.